# Replace text from VIEW Definition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I have the following `VIEW` definition:

```
create view v_1
as
select * from t1
where [date] between '2010-01-01' and '2019-01-01'
union all
select * from t2
where [date] between '2012-01-01' and '2019-01-01'
union all
select * from t3
where [date] between '2013-01-01' and '2019-01-01'
union all
select * from t4
where [date] between '2014-01-01' and '2019-01-01'
```

Scenario 1: Want to remove(or replace with empty string) `table t1` select statement.

View should look like:

```
create view v_1
as
select * from t2
where [date] between '2012-01-01' and '2019-01-01'
union all
select * from t3
where [date] between '2013-01-01' and '2019-01-01'
union all
select * from t4
where [date] between '2014-01-01' and '2019-01-01'
```

Scenario 2: Want to remove `table t4` select statement.

View should look like:

```
create view v_1
as
select * from t1
where [date] between '2010-01-01' and '2019-01-01'
union all
select * from t2
where [date] between '2012-01-01' and '2019-01-01'
union all
select * from t3
where [date] between '2013-01-01' and '2019-01-01'
```

**Note**: Depends on the requirement may want to remove any select statement from VIEW definition.

Comment: What's the point in changing the definition? Your client apps will receive unpredictable results because it would not know which data exactly returns. Create several different views or add a flag column to your current one and then filter data you need from the client side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refresh View after table drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56249310/refresh-view-after-table-drop)

Comment: This is just a kludge to your previous question. Which seems to be a kludge to your schema issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of view, create inline table function also know as view with parameters. For example:

```
create function v_1
(   
    @HasQuery1 BIT
   ,@HasQuery2 BIT
   ,@HasQuery3 BIT
   ,@HasQuery4 BIT
)
RETURNS TABLE
as
RETURN
(
select * from t1
where [date] between '2010-01-01' and '2019-01-01'
    AND @HasQuery1  = 1
union all
select * from t2
where [date] between '2012-01-01' and '2019-01-01'
    AND  @HasQuery2  = 1
union all
select * from t3
where [date] between '2013-01-01' and '2019-01-01'
    AND  @HasQuery3  = 1
union all
select * from t4
where [date] between '2014-01-01' and '2019-01-01'
    AND  @HasQuery4  = 1
)
```

You can use the function in joins like view, but you can pass which data to be returned.
For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM T1 A
INNER JOIN V_1(1, 0, 0, 1) B
   ON ....
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL server enables you to use regex as search pattern in editor, so all you need to do is:

1. Press Ctrl+F
2. Enable using regular expressions
3. As search pattern use `select.+from t1(.*\n)+?select`, where `t1` can be replaced by any table name
4. As replace pattern use `select`

See screen below (after replacing):

[image]

Comment: @MAK No, SQL server doesn't support such advanced regex in querying.

Answer (score 0):

I like @gotqn 's answer but, if it has to be a view I would do this:

```
--Sample Tables:
CREATE TABLE dbo.t1(id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, col1 INT);
CREATE TABLE dbo.t2(id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, col1 INT);
CREATE TABLE dbo.t3(id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, col1 INT);
CREATE TABLE dbo.t4(id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, col1 INT);

INSERT dbo.t1(col1) VALUES (10),(20),(30);
INSERT dbo.t2(col1) VALUES (60),(620),(630);
INSERT dbo.t3(col1) VALUES (0);
INSERT dbo.t4(col1) VALUES (0);
GO

--Solution
CREATE VIEW dbo.yourView AS
  SELECT t.*,show = 1 FROM dbo.t1 AS t UNION ALL
  SELECT t.*,show = 2 FROM dbo.t2 AS t UNION ALL
  SELECT t.*,show = 3 FROM dbo.t3 AS t UNION ALL
  SELECT t.*,show = 4 FROM dbo.t4 AS t
GO
```

What's nice here is that the optimizer is smart enough to completely ignore and avoid touching tables with data not included in the final result set.

Note these queries and the execution plans:

```
SELECT v.* FROM dbo.yourView AS v;
SELECT v.* FROM dbo.yourView AS v WHERE v.show = 1;
SELECT v.* FROM dbo.yourView AS v WHERE v.show IN (1,3);
SELECT v.* FROM dbo.yourView AS v WHERE v.show <> 1;
```

[image]